# Facebook PHP SDK app to upload photo to page

Tags: php, facebook, photo-upload

I am trying to create a Facebook application that uploads images to a page. I can manage to upload photos to the user's photo album but not to the page's.

Here's my code:

```
require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');

 $config = array(
  'appId' => 'XXXXXXXX',
  'secret' => 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY',
  'fileUpload' => true,
 );

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();    

$photo = $_POST['image'];
$message = "Lorem ipsum";

echo $user_id;

  if ($user_id) {
       $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/XXXXXXXXXX/photos', 'POST', array(
        'access_token'  => $access_token,
                    'source' => '@' . $photo,
                    'message' => $message
                                    )
                                  );

} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {

    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                   'scope' => 'user_photos,publish_stream,photo_upload'
                   )); 
         echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
    print_r($e);
            error_log($e->getType());
            error_log($e->getMessage());
  }   
  echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
 } else {

  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' =>user_photos,publish_stream,photo_upload,manage_pages' ) );
     echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Posting Photo to facebook fan page via iOS app by regular non-admin users](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10912901/posting-photo-to-facebook-fan-page-via-ios-app-by-regular-non-admin-users)

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
$facebook->api('/XXXXXXXXXX/photos', 'POST', array(
```

... is XXXXXXXXXX your appId or the albumId? You must do the call to your **album ID**.

Also make sure you are using the correct $access_token. To make sure look at:

> https://graph.facebook.com/yourPageID?fields=access_token&access_token=YourPersonalAccessToken

where yourPersonalAccessToken is:

> A Page admin `access_token` for this page; The current user must be an
>   administrator of this page; only returned if specifically requested
>   via the `fields` URL parameter.

Your must grant to graph api `manage_pages` permissions.